# XML Schema totalDigits/fractionDigits vs. SQL precision/scale

Tags: sql, xml, xsd, ddl

I'd like to find out the correspondence between XML Schema `totalDigits`/`fractionDigits` and SQL numeric precision/scale.

1) Assume we have the following simple type:

```
<xs:simpleType name="DecimalNumber">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:fractionDigits value="17"/>
        <xs:totalDigits value="18"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

How would I represent it in SQL? Let's assume HSQL dialect (it does not matter much). I'm interested in the most restrictive SQL type which could hold all the values from the value space of the XML Schema simple type.

Would it be `numeric(18,17)`? Or `numeric(35,17)`?

2) What if we have just `totalDigits`?

```
<xs:simpleType name="DecimalNumber">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:totalDigits value="18"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

What would be an adequate representation in SQL?

3) Or just `fractionDigits`?

```
<xs:simpleType name="DecimalNumber">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:fractionDigits value="17"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with this in mind:

```
scale ≡ fractionDigits
precision ≡ totalDigits
```

In HSQL:

1. DECIMAL (35, 17) -- edit: fractionDigits is an upper bound; in your case from none to 17. Hence, the domain of values to be represented ranges from 18 digits on the left, to 17 on the right (of the decimal point). So you need a scale of 17, and (18 + 17) digits to be able to represent the max values: 18 digits with no decimal digits.
2. A naïve translation to DECIMAL (18) really means 18 digits without a decimal point since the scale is defaulted to 0 - not XSD's equivalent. To allow capturing all numbers, one would need to code DECIMAL (36, 18) which would exceed, in terms of domain values, what's representable by XSD's 18 total digits. You'll have to make a call here.
3. In SQL, I am not aware of a way to specify scale without precision. Since XSD doesn't provide an upper limit (it asks for a minimum of 18)... you may have to just choose a number, maybe as limited by your infrastructure (e.g. MS-SQL has max 38 precision), or don't bother at all (Apache's HsqlDB uses unlimited precision and scale).

Comment: Are you sure about `precision ≡ totalDigits`? I think 12340000 has 4 `totalDigits` but 8 `precision`.

Comment: I am sure. The trailing zeroes are significant in your example, therefore counted by totalDigits. If you would've said 1234.0000 (dot = decimal point) then yes, 4 digits is enough.

Comment: But in 1) doesn't `9.99999999999999999` the maximum what DECIMAL(18,17) allows?

Comment: Yes, that is be the maximum value for SQL. I see your point. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. If I may still expand on one thing that puzzled me: why do we need a precision of (totalDigits + fractionDigits)? Because all written values will be scaled down by a factor of 'scale', when reading. If no fractional part was included, we still have to scale up the value on write, because it will be scaled down on read. In that regard, is the leading part of the answer not a bit misleading? As it turns out, one could say scale ≡ fractionDigits, and precision ≡ totalDigits + fractionDigits.

Comment: @WildPottok, the precision is not totalDigits + fractionDigits. Precision is referred to as simply the total number of digits needed to represent a number, with or without decimal separator.  Scale/fractional digits is the number of digits to the right of the decimal separator. It may help to read the definitions of precision and scale from your favorite SQL engine, and totalDigits and fractionDigits from XSD schema types, hopefully it'll clear it up for you.

Comment: Many thanks, Petru Gardea. Well, I have read the docs for PostgreSQL, Oracle and SQL Server, which are in line with your statement. Unfortunately, I still seem to miss something; the clearest way in which I could express this puzzlement is to respectfully ask: "If precision is simply the total number of digits needed to represent a number, with or without decimal separator, then why do we need a precision of 35=17 + 18 = totalDigits + fractionDigits"?

Comment: @WildPottok, I think you are missing out the range incongruence. Imagine you define a table with a column numeric(5,4). The SQL maximum value to the left of the decimal separator will be 9 since the maximum number of digits to the left as 5 - 4. However, in XSD one could have 99999 or 0.9999 for totalDigits 5, fractional 4. So, to capture the XSD *range* in a SQL column, you have to correctly provision the min-max values. I just tested the above against XSD 1.0 and MS SQL 2016, the behavior is as described above.